# How to check if button was clicked in twig?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I want to have a button in my twig file in a table that removes an element from an array, preferably the index.

In the research I've done, I keep seeing that any data manipulation should remain in the controller. I'm sure I can accomplish my solution with jquery but doesn't that break the data manipulation rule? Or should something be done in the controller? I tried seeing if button isset using POST but that didn't work...

Essentially, once this button is clicked, the corresponding element's index is removed from the array. How can I accomplish this the best way possible?

Also I've only watched a few tutorials on jquery so I'm a complete beginner. If it's ok, how can I accomplish this using jquery?

My attempt at jquery:

```
cartArray.splice($.inArray(removeItem, cartArray), [0]);
```

... Where 0 is the index...I know this doesn't work, as I need index to know which element is being selected.

In twig file:

```
            <tbody>
                {% for key, cartValue in cartArray %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ cartValue[0] }}</td> <!--Product-->
                        <td>{{ cartValue[1] }}</td> <!--Quantity-->
                        <td>${{ cartValue[2] }}</td> <!--Price Per Unit-->
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}    
            </tbody>
```

I should mention I'm using bootstrap as well.

In Controller:

```
$cartArray = array();

    if (is_null($cartArray) || !$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Error: Nothin in Array/Entity');
    } else {
        $cartArray = $session->get('cartArray', []);

        $cartArray[$entity->getId()] = [$entity->getName(), $entity->getQuantity(), $entity->getPrice()];

        foreach ($cartArray as $key => $product) {
                // dump($cartArray); die;
                // dump($key); die;
                $productEntity = $em->getRepository('PaTShopTestBundle:Product')->find($key);
                $quantity = $productEntity->getQuantity();
                $price = $productEntity->getPrice();
                $totalCostOfAllProducts += $price * $quantity;
        }
    }

    //$remove = unset($cartArray);

    // if (isset($_POST['Button'])) {
    //     unset($cartArray[1]); //remove index
    // }



    $session->set('cartArray', $cartArray); //session---------------

    //var_dump($cartArray); die;

    return array(
        'price'     => $price,
        'quantity'  => $quantity,
        'totalCostOfAllProducts'   => $totalCostOfAllProducts,
        'cartArray'   => $cartArray,
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
```

Any help is really appreciated, Thanks Again!

Comment: What is the method ? Is the method that display the view ? Or a POST method that processes a form or other data ? If it's a method that you call from the view by clicking a link, pass some a route|get|post parameters

Comment: /** 
     * Creates the option to 'add product to cart'.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/cart", name="product_cart")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */

Comment: That would be the best way to describe it I think.

Comment: `fruits.shift();  // Removes the first element from an array and returns only that element.` - 
`fruits.pop();    // Removes the last element from an array and returns only that element.`

Comment: @SpYk3HH That's not what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: `var i = $('#ele').index(); array.splice(i, 1);`

Comment: `.splice([index in Array], [number of items to remove])`

Comment: @SpYk3HH Could you provide a formatted answer, because jquery really is totally new to me?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```js
//  Simple variables, one for building a sentence from the array
//  and one that will be our element array
var sentence = '',
    araEle = $('li');

//  first I build the sentence for display before any removal
araEle.each(function(i) { sentence += (i>0?' ':'') + $(this).text(); });
//  here i use a simple jQuery/css selector to get the first fieldset's p tag
$('fieldset:first p').text(sentence);

//  here will pretend our button was clicked and our index is 4
var index = 4;
//  this is simple, old fashioned vanilla JS, 
//  there is no better jQuery alternative, 
//  which is why they didn't make one.
//  the first param is the zero based index value
//  the second param is how many to count from there
//  second value is 1 if you only want to remove the one item AT index
var returnsValue = araEle.splice(index, 1);
//  and as the variable assigned says
//  if you get a return from it, it will be the item,
//  in this case an element,
//  at that index
//  SO, if you wanted to remove the element itself afterward you could say:
$(returnsValue).remove();

//  reset our sentence string
sentence = '';
//  rebuild our sentence
araEle.each(function(i) { sentence += (i>0?' ':'') + $(this).text(); });
//  again simple jQuery/css selector to get the last fieldset's p tag
//  and display new sentence
$('fieldset:last p').text(sentence);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="zero">This</li>
  <li id="one">is</li>
  <li id="two">jusT</li>
  <li id="three">a</li>
  <li id="four">[TesT]</li>
  <li id="five">lisT</li>
 </ul>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Sentence Before Array Removal</legend>
  <p></p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Sentence After Array Splice at Index 4(TesT)</legend>
  <p></p>
</fieldset>
```